# Azure CLI not installed. But it really is

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, gradle, azure-cli

Hi everyone Thanks in advance for your help.

Context: I am trying to running a SpringBoot Application (Locally) which use (connect) Azure to get Env vars. I am using Manjaro OS. (Linux)

The project compiles well, Intellij index well, I mean in general all look good.

When I try to run the Task of Gradlle ***bootRun*** which run the spring app, it fails with this error:

```
2022-06-01 08:29:29.645 ERROR 4349 --- [smos-parallel-1] trace[] span[] c.a.i.implementation.IdentityClient      : AzureCliCredential authentication unavailable. Azure CLI not installed.To mitigate this issue, please refer to the troubleshooting guidelines here at https://aka.ms/azsdk/java/identity/azclicredential/troubleshoot
```

Finding in the page where the error is showing I am aware that all the installation that I have, is ok.
I mean, Path var is ok, ***az login*** command runs ok.

Then in summary in my Manjaro Linux OS I have installed azure cli and I already Signed in it, but when I run the spring boot app, I have the error that I already showed.
Here the full log.

```
2022-06-01 08:29:29.645 ERROR 4349 --- [smos-parallel-1] trace[] span[] c.a.i.implementation.IdentityClient      : AzureCliCredential authentication unavailable. Azure CLI not installed.To mitigate this issue, please refer to the troubleshooting guidelines here at https://aka.ms/azsdk/java/identity/azclicredential/troubleshoot
2022-06-01 08:29:29.646 ERROR 4349 --- [smos-parallel-1] trace[] span[] c.a.i.implementation.IdentityClient      : AzureCliCredential authentication unavailable. Azure CLI not installed.To mitigate this issue, please refer to the troubleshooting guidelines here at https://aka.ms/azsdk/java/identity/azclicredential/troubleshoot
2022-06-01 08:29:29.647 ERROR 4349 --- [smos-parallel-1] trace[] span[] com.azure.identity.AzureCliCredential    : Azure Identity => ERROR in getToken() call for scopes [https://xxxxxxxxx.documents.azure.com/.default]: AzureCliCredential authentication unavailable. Azure CLI not installed.To mitigate this issue, please refer to the troubleshooting guidelines here at https://aka.ms/azsdk/java/identity/azclicredential/troubleshoot
2022-06-01 08:29:29.648 ERROR 4349 --- [smos-parallel-1] trace[] span[] c.a.core.credential.SimpleTokenCache     : Failed to acquire a new access token.
2022-06-01 08:29:29.652 ERROR 4349 --- [smos-parallel-1] trace[] span[] c.a.c.i.GlobalEndpointManager            : Fail to reach global gateway [https://xxxxxxxxxx.documents.azure.com:443/], [AzureCliCredential authentication unavailable. Azure CLI not installed.To mitigate this issue, please refer to the troubleshooting guidelines here at https://aka.ms/azsdk/java/identity/azclicredential/troubleshoot]
2022-06-01 08:29:29.656 ERROR 4349 --- [smos-parallel-1] trace[] span[] c.a.c.i.GlobalEndpointManager            : startRefreshLocationTimerAsync() - Unable to refresh database account from any location. Exception: com.azure.identity.CredentialUnavailableException: AzureCliCredential authentication unavailable. Azure CLI not installed.To mitigate this issue, please refer to the troubleshooting guidelines here at https://aka.ms/azsdk/java/identity/azclicredential/troubleshoot

com.azure.identity.CredentialUnavailableException: AzureCliCredential authentication unavailable. Azure CLI not installed.To mitigate this issue, please refer to the troubleshooting guidelines here at https://aka.ms/azsdk/java/identity/azclicredential/troubleshoot
    at com.azure.identity.implementation.IdentityClient.authenticateWithAzureCli(IdentityClient.java:472)
    at com.azure.identity.AzureCliCredential.getToken(AzureCliCredential.java:39)
    at com.azure.cosmos.implementation.RxDocumentClientImpl.lambda$new$0(RxDocumentClientImpl.java:331)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:44)
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFromMonoOperator.subscribe(FluxFromMonoOperator.java:83)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefer.subscribe(FluxDefer.java:54)
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:157)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDelay$MonoDelayRunnable.propagateDelay(MonoDelay.java:271)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDelay$MonoDelayRunnable.run(MonoDelay.java:286)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ReactorSleuth.lambda$null$6(ReactorSleuth.java:312)
    at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:68)
    at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:28)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

2022-06-01 08:29:29.657 ERROR 4349 --- [           main] trace[] span[] c.a.c.i.RxDocumentClientImpl             : Client initialization failed. Check if the endpoint is reachable and if your auth token is valid. More info: https://aka.ms/cosmosdb-tsg-service-unavailable-java
2022-06-01 08:29:29.658 ERROR 4349 --- [           main] trace[] span[] c.a.c.i.RxDocumentClientImpl             : unexpected failure in initializing client.
```

Comment: [Troubleshoot AzureCliCredential Authentication Issues](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/main/sdk/identity/azure-identity/TROUBLESHOOTING.md#troubleshoot-azureclicredential-authentication-issues)

Comment: Thanks, but as I mentioned, this link I already visited, and I validated that all are ok. :(

Answer (score 3):

I get the answer.

The problem was caused by Intellij, since this one for some reason was not taking the PATH variable.
How I can solve it?

run in my terminal:

```
echo $PATH
```

Edit your run configuration adding the env variable, something like that:
[image]

And that's it!!

Comment: Thanks a ton, I was facing the same issue and setting path resolved error